# Why does solar current drop when charging a battery with a MPP controller?

Tags: batteries, solar-cell, mppt

I'm trying to build a model using a PV panel to charge a battery (a buck converter in between). I use a MPP controller to track the maximum power point. The solar irradiance and temperature are set as constant values.

I see when the battery is charging, the battery voltage increases with the SoC increase.
But at the same time, the PV current decreases and the PV voltage increases.

One thing is that if the maximum power point is tracked, and the battery voltage increases, then the current decrease seems reasonable because P = V*I.
But it also seems that the PV current is decided by the solar irradiance, so it should also be constant.

Therefore I'm quite confused here.
I wonder what should the PV current and voltage look like when the battery is charging?
And if the PV current should be constant, what should I change in the MPP controller?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: It depends. Is it during the CC charging stage or during the CV charging stage?

Comment: I didn't specify a control to charge the battery in CC or CV mode. But the initial SoC of the battery is 10%. With your question, I run the model again with an initial SoC of 60%, and this time the battery voltage is nearly constant, while the PV current and voltage are also nearly constant. Does that mean when SoC = 0.1, the battery is in CC charging stage, while when SoC = 0.6, the battery is in CV charging stage?

Comment: " Does that mean when SoC = 0.1, the battery is in CC charging stage" Yes. "while when SoC = 0.6, the battery is in CV charging stage". Unlikely but possible. It look like you don't know what CC and CV are, and that you did not implement them. You must.